# UserName is null for a user in SharePoint REST API result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to get user's information using REST call to a list. The list named "Members" has two fields:

Team: Single line of text

User: Person or group

The code piece for REST call is below:

```
var queryUrl = "<web url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Members')/items?$select=User/UserName,User/EMail&$expand=User";

jQuery.ajax({
    url: queryUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.d.results);                        
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);          
    }
});
```

There are few items in the 'Members' list. The issue I'm facing is that for some users the 'User/UserName' value is returned null.

How can I debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a case that username is empty in UserProfile.

Try to fetch other user properties:

```
$select=Users/EMail,Users/FirstName,Users/LastName&$expand=Users
```